# spring mvc placeholders in angular js filter

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-mvc

I'm studying angular js and I just read about the filters, so I was wondering if an integration of spring mvc with angular filters can be done. the result I would like to achieve is a responsive search for an input:
you write in an input box and everything(recovered from db in the spring controller) filtered is shown. something like:

```
    public class HomeController{
        @Autowired
        private ApplicationContext context;
        @Autowired
        private UserDao userDao;

        @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public String showResult{ModelMap map){
            map.addAttribute("listUsers", userDao.getAllUsers());
            return("home");
        }
    }
```

Now, what I want to do in the jsp is something like this (I know it's not right)

```
<input data-ng-model="search" type="text">
<ol>
  <li data-ng-repeat="user in ${listUsers} | filter:{${user.name} : search}">
    <div class="row">{{user.name}}</div>
  </li>
</ol>
```

even something like this would be great:

```
data-ng-init="listUser=${listUsers}"
```

I know I will study REST controller and ajax post methods and everything will be fine, but is there a way to reach the same result now with a syntax similiar to this shown here(without services)?
Thank you for the help

Comment: No, jsp runs on server not in browser where angular runs and ng-repeat needs to reference angular scope. They are not interchangeable between the 2 languages

Comment: Logic is all wrong. If you need data from server based on user input, you need to make requests from browser to server to get that specific data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution was: web services exposed in a rest spring controller. Then fetch the data from an angular controller and then show it inside the html code. Non need for spring tags because they don't work in conjunction with the angular scopes.